# MySQL using OR with MATCH AGAINST slows query drastically

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, sql-like, full-text-indexing

Columns are indexed and fulltext. Why does the "OR" add 5-8 seconds?

```
SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
// returns in .05 seconds
SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE someColumn LIKE 'testing123%' 
// returns in .003 seconds
SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE (MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
// returns in 5-8 seconds; yes, they are same MATCH statement...
SELECT * FROM exampleTable WHERE (MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)OR someOtherIndexedColumn LIKE 'testing123%' 
// returns in 5-8 seconds; ***** different columns this time*******
```

I find it odd that MySQL is so slow when it's the same statement. It's like causing the statement **"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1 OR 1 "** to be 5 seconds. Whether the columns are the same or different makes no difference in speed.

Comment: Which version of MySQL server?

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though MySQL 5.0+ now supports [Index Merge](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html), there currently is this limitation:

> Index Merge is not applicable to full-text indexes. We plan to extend
>   it to cover these in a future MySQL release.

Typically, you can rewrite these into `UNION` queries:

```
SELECT * FROM exampleTable
WHERE MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION
SELECT * FROM exampleTable
WHERE MATCH(someColumn) AGAINST('+testing123*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I'll be running two queries and merging the results myself then :(

Comment: Above and beyond with the example UNION. Thanks again!